# Angularjs ng-repeat passed index not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to toggle the button on and off in a ng-repeat, view on map works, but when it changes to remove marker, it pass me an error 'ReferenceError: passedIndex is not defined' in console log. Any way to fix that?

HTML:

```
            <li class="displaySubCategory" ng-repeat="communityTheme in community | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
              <div class="categoryImg">
                <img src="img/csvIcon.png" />
                <img src="img/shpIcon.png" />
              </div>
              <div class="categoryDesc">
                <p>{{communityTheme.THEMENAME}}</p>
                <a href="" ng-hide="communityTheme.visibility" ng-click="getMapData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME, $index)">View on Map</a>
                <a href="" ng-show="communityTheme.visibility" ng-click="removeMarker(communityTheme.QUERYNAME, $index)">Remove Marker</a>
              </div>
            </li>
```

JS:

```
        $scope.getMapData = function (msg, passedIndex) {
                map.addLayer(cities);

                $scope.Lng.length = 0;
                $scope.Lat.length = 0;
                $scope.dataLatLng.length = 0;

               queryNameUrl = 'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=' + msg +
               '&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQwOTI5OTE2LCJleHAiOjE1NDEzNjE5MTYsIm5iZiI6MTU0MDkyOTkxNiwianRpIjoiYjVkNmZkNGJhOWJiNGJiM2FkNWQzN2ZhNTAzMGIxYWEifQ.YQdfV43wrg8dX-He7-mwIL2Qhjsexq0tgNu5RotAdu4';
               $http.get(queryNameUrl).then(function(response) {
                 $scope.apiResult = response.data.SrchResults;
                 $scope.apiResult.splice(0,1);
                 console.log($scope.apiResult)

                       for (var i= 0; i < $scope.apiResult.length; i++) {
                            if ($scope.apiResult[i].Type == "Point"){
                              $scope.apiResult[i].visibility = true;
                              console.log($scope.apiResult)
                              $scope.dataLatLng.push($scope.apiResult[i].LatLng)
                              $scope.Lat.push($scope.dataLatLng[i].split(',')[0]);
                              $scope.Lng.push($scope.dataLatLng[i].split(',')[1]);
                              L.marker([$scope.Lat[i], $scope.Lng[i]], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup($scope.apiResult[i].DESCRIPTION).addTo(cities);
                            }
                              // else if ($scope.apiResult[i].Type == "Polygon"){
                              //       $scope.PolyLine.push($scope.apiResult[i].LatLng)
                              //       console.log($scope.PolyLine)
                              //       // for (var i = 0; i < $scope.PolyLine.length; i++) {
                              //       //     $scope.polyLineCord.push($scope.PolyLine[i])
                              //       //     // console.log($scope.polyLineCord)
                              //       // }
                              //   }
                       }
               })
               if($scope.community[passedIndex].visibility)
                {
                  $scope.community[passedIndex].visibility = false;
                }
               else{
                 $scope.community[passedIndex].visibility = true;
               }
        }
```

Remove Marker:

```
        $scope.removeMarker = function ($index) {

            if($scope.community[passedIndex].visibility)
             {
               $scope.community[passedIndex].visibility =false;
               cities.clearLayers();
             }
            else {
              $scope.community[passedIndex].visibility = true;
            }
        }
```

Thanks for the help in advance !

[image]

Comment: your function definition is wrong.  try `$scope.removeMarker = function (passedIndex) {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use track by $index

```
 <li class="displaySubCategory" ng-repeat="communityTheme in community | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize track by $index">
```

and it should be **`passedIndex`** instead of **`$index`** in your removeMarker function

```
$scope.removeMarker = function (passedIndex) {
```

Comment: @HangulSR as claies mentioned in the above comment, the argument should be passedIndex, check edited answer

Comment: are u still here? Any idea why now it says
Cannot read property 'visibility' of undefined ? I added the visibility in my view on map function, y is it still undefined in my remove marker function ?

Comment: add a console.log($scope.community[passedIndex]) and see if it has visibility

Comment: Ya, its undefined. Why is that so? Is it because of asynchronous or something? @Sajeetharan

Comment: which means $scope.community does not hold values, yeah you need to check using if($scope.community)

Comment: arghh~ Any way on how to fix that?

Comment: i wonder it should be already there since you are doing ng-repeat, just check $scope.community has value inside the function

Comment: hmm, thats weird. It does have value, but it says undefined

Comment: Oh wait, i think i know whats the problem

Comment: mind looking at what i updated, i thought i got it, but the problem's still there